# CDI errors on Tests

Tags: testing, cdi, jboss-arquillian, wildfly-swarm, thorntail

I'm building an application using Wildfly Swarm 2018.5.0.

When I setup the application tests, every thing works fine in an "Hello World" application, but when I add it to my application with all dependencies, there is a lot of erros like: **Unsatisfied dependencies for type LoggingFraction with qualifiers @Any**

How the best approach to fix this errors and setup correctly my tests? This is an Wildfly Swarm bug? There is any way to make it work? Just for clarify I had updated to Thorntail 2.1.0.Final, and I have a similar problem with *jandex* dependency. Works in a "Hello World", but when I add some dependency I have errors.
For now I'm developing without test, and I do not like to do that! :(

```
2018-08-27 10:20:48,696 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Validator] (MSC service thread 1-2) WELD-001471: Interceptor method setupFactories defined on class org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.xmlconfig.StandaloneXMLParserProducer is not defined according to the specification. It should not throw java.lang.Exception, which is a checked exception.
    at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.xmlconfig.StandaloneXMLParserProducer.setupFactories(StandaloneXMLParserProducer.java:0)
  StackTrace
2018-08-27 10:20:48,698 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Validator] (MSC service thread 1-2) WELD-001471: Interceptor method postConstruct defined on class org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.wildfly.ShrinkWrapFileSystem is not defined according to the specification. It should not throw java.io.IOException, which is a checked exception.
    at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.wildfly.ShrinkWrapFileSystem.postConstruct(ShrinkWrapFileSystem.java:0)
  StackTrace
2018-08-27 10:20:48,730 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."FirmwareTest.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."FirmwareTest.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1978)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 2 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type LoggingFraction with qualifiers @Any
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @Any private org.wildfly.swarm.logging.runtime.EarlyLoggingCustomizer.fraction
  at org.wildfly.swarm.logging.runtime.EarlyLoggingCustomizer.fraction(EarlyLoggingCustomizer.java:0)

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:362)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:284)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:158)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:501)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:61)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:59)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Exception 1 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type LoggingFraction with qualifiers @Any
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @Any private org.wildfly.swarm.logging.runtime.LoggingCustomizer.fraction
  at org.wildfly.swarm.logging.runtime.LoggingCustomizer.fraction(LoggingCustomizer.java:0)

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:362)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:284)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:158)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:501)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:61)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:59)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator.validateBeans(ConcurrentValidator.java:69)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:462)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:477)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:90)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:96)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)
    ... 3 more
```

The error is reproduced in this branch: https://github.com/vepo/microprofile-tutorial/tree/error